# getting value of action in ember route-action helper

Tags: ember.js, action, helper

Please refer to this issue:
https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper/issues/27

I am facing similar issue, posting it here again:

Is there any solution to this issue?
I am trying to use route-action helper for checkbox as follows:
Select All

It calls my action inside route, but it is passing some event object instead of checked value (I am expecting true/false) like it does for the usual action helper:

I am also facing the same issue while using select drodown:

-- JDBC or HDFS load? -- 
JDBC
HDFS
Here I am expecting to get the values JDBC or HDFS when the actions is fired.

If it can be done by writing action to receive full event, please give some example how to extract required information from the event.

I am new to ember. Please help.

Comment: Could you copy details of the issue over from GitHub so they can be read inline here?

Comment: Did you try `<input type="checkbox" onchange={{action (route-action "selectAllTables") value="target.checked"}}>`?

Comment: Gennady's suggestion should be the accepted answer